# Why Select Query by Restriction Not IN cannot execute normally, but by Restriction IN can?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to select some material data from one Table, and have one restriction, that the material should not exists in one View.

So, below is my code. It cannot be executed normally.

```
select *
from Table A
where Table A.Material not in (select View A.material from View A)
```

This Query always executes and till over time.
But if I use Restriction IN, it can execute normally.

```
select *
from Table A
where Table A.Material in (select View A.material from View A)
```

To get the target data, I use below code, and it works.

```
select *
from Table A
where Table A.Material not in (select *
                               from Table A 
                               where Table A.Material in (select View A.material from View A)
                              )
```

It is strange, so where is the problem for my original code?

Comment: It seems the problem of IN and NOT IN

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some NULL-s in `ViewA.material`. Another way to solve your problem is:

```
select * from TableA where TableA.Material not in (select ViewA.material from ViewA where ViewA.material IS NOT NULL)
```

Let's suppose that `ViewA.material` has the values 1, 2 and NULL. The query with `IN` would be equivalent to:

```
select * from TableA where Material=1 OR Material=2 OR Material=NULL
```

Even if TableA would contain a row with NULL, the condition `Material=NULL` will not be true, because NULL=NULL is unknown (at least under the default and recommended setting of `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`). However `TRUE OR unknown` produces `TRUE`, so this query produces the correct results.

The query with `NOT IN` would be equivalent to:

```
select * from TableA where Material<>1 AND Material<>2 AND Material<>NULL
```

In this case `TRUE AND unknown` produces `unknown`, so this query will never return any results.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot and it quite helps me to strengthen this part knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

That's a question of NOT IN, it does cause some issues:
This is 1st link: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/
And this is another discussion in this subject: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists

It could be because you're using the VIEW, not the TABLE. The TABLE has probably indexes, whereas the VIEW doesn't, and that's where you lose optimisation by the engine. If you try to see the [plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017), you'll probably see quite quickly what's going on